# Is ASP.NET SqlPersonalizationProvider a good option for storing user settings?

Tags: asp.net, personalization

I am designing my data model for my application and I have run across SqlPersonalizationProvider. Is this intended for storing user settings such as Time Zone selection and other common settings? If so does anyone have any links to good tutorials? I have already determined I will use TableProfileProvider for additional profile information. Is this the correct provider for settings (SqlPersonalizationProvider)?

Thanks,
Darren